# How to store result of simple python calculator in variable

Tags: python, calculator

I am a beginner to Python and have just started learning recently.

After learning about if, elif and else statements I decided to try and make a simple calculator.

Now, a few hours later I was wondering how I could improve it and make it more complex.

I am trying to store the result of the addition, subtraction, divison or multiplication of the first two numbers in a variable. After doing this I want to Re-create the calculator only I already have the first number.

I am also running into problems with my continue1 if statement, for some reason even if the user inputs "no" the script continues instead of displaying a message.

I'd really appreciate any help at all, Thank you!

Python code:

```
num1 = float(input("Please enter your first number: "))
num2 = float(input("Please enter your second number: "))
operator = input("Please enter operator: ")

if operator == "/":
    print(num1 / num2)
elif operator == "+":
    print(num1 + num2)
elif operator == "-":
    print(num1 - num2)
elif operator == "*":
    print(num1 * num2)
else:
    print("FATAL ERROR")

num3 = num1 / num2
num3 = num1 - num2
num3 = num1 + num2
num3 = num1 * num2


continue1 =  input ("Would you like too continue? [Yes/No]")


if continue1 == "yes" or "Yes":
    operator1 = num4 = float(input("Please enter second number: "))
else:
    print("Fatal error")

input("please enter operator")

if operator == "/":
    print(num3 / num4)
elif operator == "+":
    print(num3 + num4)
elif operator == "-":
    print(num3 - num4)
elif operator == "*":
    print(num3 * num4)
else:
    print("Please press enter to close.")



input("Press Enter to Exit")
```

Comment: Whatever you do, this code will keep as result, the value of `num3 = num1 * num2`. You should put these lines in each if, elif

Comment: Also, the second time you ask for an operator, you do not store it in a variable. So you use the previous operator, which is already stored

Comment: This if works.`if continue1 in ["yes", "Yes"]:`

Comment: @Phineas "Whatever you do, this code will keep as result, the value of num3 = num1 * num2" - Actually not, the code will raise an error if you try to multiply by 0 because `num3 = num1 / num2` gets executed anyway.

Comment: Ok, of course 0 is a different case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first part, just assign to a variable (and then print it if you want):

```
if operator == "/":
    num3 = num1 / num2
elif operator == "+":
    num3 = num1 + num2
elif operator == "-":
    num3 = num1 - num2
elif operator == "*":
    num3 = num1 * num2
else:
    print("FATAL ERROR")

print(num3)
```

Regarding the second part of your question, in your statement:

```
if continue1 == "yes" or "Yes":
```

this is wrong because `or` is an operator which will combine the two things on either side of it (typically used where each of these two things is something that evaluates to `True` or `False`), so you could have for example:

```
if continue1 == "yes" or continue1 == "Yes":
```

You can also add brackets to control the order of execution, as shown below.  In this case they do not affect the result, because it is already the case that the `==` operators are evaluated before the `or`, but they may make it clearer to read.

```
if (continue1 == "yes") or (continue1 == "Yes"):
```

You can also do this instead:

```
if continue1 in ("yes", "Yes"):
```

The details of what is going wrong with your original form of the conditional statement are perhaps not important at this stage, but I mention them for sake of completeness. If you enter `"No"` then the whole expression will actually evaluate to `"Yes"` (the `continue1 == "yes"` evaluates to `False`, and then `False or "Yes"` evalues to `"Yes"`). The `if` statement then treats the value `"Yes"` (a non-empty string) as a true value and so executes the code which depends on the condition.

Answer (score 0):

I recreated your code now it's working:

```
def op(operator,num1,num2):
    global num3
    if operator == "/":
        num3 = num1 / num2
    elif operator == "+":
        num3 = num1 + num2
    elif operator == "-":
        num3 = num1 - num2
    elif operator == "*":
        num3 = num1 * num2
    else:
        print("FATAL ERROR")

num1 = float(input("Please enter your first number: "))
num2 = float(input("Please enter your second number: "))
operator = input("Please enter operator: ")
op(operator,num1,num2)
print(num3)

continue1 =  input ("Would you like too continue? [Yes/No]").lower()

if continue1 in ["yes", "y"]:
    num4 = float(input("Please enter second number: "))
    operator = input("please enter operator")
    op(operator,num3,num4)
    print(num3)
else:
    print("Fatal error")

input("Press Enter to Exit")
```

Comment: Because of  `.lower()` all the inputs are in simple letters.

Answer (score 0):

```
num1 = float(input("Please enter your first number: "))
num2 = float(input("Please enter your second number: "))
keepCalculate=True
while keepCalculate:
    operator = input("Please enter operator: ")
    if operator == "/":
        print(num1 / num2)
    elif operator == "+":
        print(num1 + num2)
    elif operator == "-":
        print(num1 - num2)
    elif operator == "*":
        print(num1 * num2)
    else:
        print("FATAL ERROR")

    continue1 =  input ("Would you like too continue? [Yes/No]")
    if continue1== "yes" or "Yes":
       keepCalculate=True
    else:
        keepCalculate=False
```

The most simple way todo what you want

Answer (score 0):

1. simply use

   num3 = num1 + num2

to store the codes

2. "or" in programming doesn't work like or in rel life, it is ussed to separate 2 different conditions, hence use:

   if continue1 == "yes" or continue1 == "Yes":

Comment: if he uses `.lower()` no need `continue1 == "Yes"`.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you do, this code will keep as result, the value of num3 = num1 * num2. You should put these lines in each if, elif